# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string error" After adding "libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar"

Tags: android, gradle, bar-chart

e*I found this error after adding compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar'). It work properly before adding mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar*

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.pnp.papps.schoob, PID: 11781
                                                                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1616)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1587)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4868)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4463)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4403)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**

> I found this error after adding  compile
>   files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar'). It work properly befor
>   adding mpandroidchartlibrary-2-1-6.jar .

**

Comment: lots of these around : https://www.google.com/search?q=noclassdeffounderror+site%3Astackoverflow.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Are you using multiDex? I've seen this a number of times, you add a dependency then the number of methodes is >65k and you need multiDex, or you get NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: yes,Configuring  App for Multidex with Gradle work for me.I think it's multiDex issue

Answer (score 13):

**
Finally this work for me..

->Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle.
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle**

**1)Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class**

```
       android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

'}'

**2) In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element.

Add following line in the application  tag of manifest file.**

```
<application

        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Comment: Thank you sir.. my project can now resume!

Comment: Thanks! Recenlty installed Android Studio 2.0 and literally broke all my projects.. spend 2 hours fixing errors.. this was the last one.

Answer (score 4):

In Manifest -> Application add below line

```
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

**Note:** If you have already any Application class just extend that application class with **MultiDexApplication**

Answer (score 0):

In app build.gradle file

```
android {  
  defaultConfig { 
     multiDexEnabled true 
   }  
}

dependencies { 
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

than in your Application class extends MultiDexApplication class

```
 public class myApplication extends MultiDexApplication {  
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate(); 
    }
 }
```

than in your Manifest add myApplication class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.demo.application">
<application
    ....
    android:name=".myApplication">
    ....
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists even after enabling multidex and everything make sure you have compiledSdkVersion compatible with the build tools...

I am not sure but I had some app with this and the problem persisted:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

It worked after changing to something like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```