# Getting ANDROID_ID Failed resolution of ...R$string;

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio (SDK version 23), and trying to obtain ANDROID_ID by following the top answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

After importing the 'secure' class, when I try the suggested answer below, I get a "cannot resolve method getContext()" warning:

```
private String androidId = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I did a bit of digging around, and thought getApplicationContext() was worth a try:

```
private String androidId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I don't get any warnings, and the app builds successfully. However if I try running it on a connected device, it crashes with the following error (summarized):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
>
> at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.(Unknown Source)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/application.myproject/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

The app doesn't crash when I manually specify my androidId string:

```
private String androidId = "This works";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have a problem with "com.google.android.gms"; which is google play services

Comment: In build.gradle (app), I've specified: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831445/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstring-error-after-ad).

In this case, it seemed the error was being caused by [excessive dependencies](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) (>65k) methods. It was corrected as follows:

**Step 1**

Modify gradle.build (app) to reference the MultiDexApplication class

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {

    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}

    ...

dependencies {
    ...

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**Step 2**

Add the following attribute to the application tag in the manifest file:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You might contain underscore in name of string, check it after removing underscore....**