# Crash at runtime after migrating to Android Studio ( NoSuchMethodError )

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I migrated to Android studio, everything seemed ok up until I tried to run the app.
It got stuck in the Launcher activity and then crashed, printing:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(ILjava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Status; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status' appears in /data/data/com.MY PACKAGE/files/instant-run/dex/slice-google-play-........b-classes.dex)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1759)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1728)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5534)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5045)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1459)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Did you added your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml???

Comment: Of course.. I migrated a working project from Eclipse, with all its folder, manfiests ,etc.

Comment: @BVtp...I ran into the same problem today...did you ever find out the answer to your issue?

Answer (score 10):

For me it was the Problem, that the versions of different of my play service dependencies differed, like

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' /different version
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
}
```

should be changed to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
}
```

I hope it works for you or somebody running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your manifest file

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

and also add this to your gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**second solution:**

add this to your launcher activity's onCreate() method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
 Context context = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
  MultiDex.install(context );
  super.onCreate(arguments);
...
}
```

**or**

needed to add this in class that extends Application:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

for more detail : 
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334130/google-gcm-android-crashes-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android)  , [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831445/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstring-error-after-ad) , [link 3](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), [link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161671/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzmp)

Hope it works..

Comment: `Context context = this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();`

Comment: I tried just passing 'this' to MultiDex.install. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got similar crash of missing method, because I had to *update recently added library version* in my `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score -1):

Add google play services dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'//update with latest version
}
```

or this,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'//update with latest version
```

Clean the project & rebuild

Comment: Adding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'` worked for me

Comment: @Brandon Good to hear that, updating with latest version works at times.